# Difference between "gemein" and "gemeinsam"

Tags: word-usage, difference, usage

I know that *gemein* also means *nasty* or *mean*, but if we keep that aside for the time being, and consider only the meaning *common*, what's the difference between the two?

Are they perfectly interchangeable?

Comment: "Gemein" ist ein sehr interessantes Wort. Es gibt mehr als diese zwei Bedeutungen. Es bedeutet auch "einfach" (das gemeine Volk) und kann auch für "vulgär" verwendet werden; oder als Intensifier. Oder "auf die Allgemeinheit bezogen". Oder synonym zu "unerfreulich". Oder, oder, oder... Am häufigsten findet man es aber als Synyonym für "fies" (Du bist gemein). Im Bezug auf "gemeinsam" wird es imho nur als Adverb, fast nie als Adjektiv verwendet. (Sie haben diese Eigenschaft gemein, nicht *Sie habe eine gemeine Eigenschaft). Die gemeine Stubenfliege, wenn auch nervig, ist übrigens nicht fies. ;)

Comment: Mein erster Gedanke war die Taxonomie von Pflanzen und Tieren, z.B. die gemeine Wespe, als die weitverbreiteste Wespenart. Der Wikipediaartikel zu _gemein_ ist auch empfehlenswert: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemein

Answer (score 5):

## gemein

From [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/gemein):

> *Bedeutungen:*
>
> (1) ursprünglich: eine Eigenschaft, die Mehrere gemeinsam hatten, habend
>
> *Beispiele:*
>
> (1) all diesen Leuten ist die Muttersprache Deutsch gemein.

[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gemein#Bedeutung4) lists a rather extensive description for usage of *gemein*:

> (4)   etwas mit jemandem, etwas gemein haben (mit jemandem, etwas etwas Gemeinsames, eine gemeinsame Eigenschaft haben, in bestimmter Weise zusammengehören: mit dem Vorgängermodell hat die Küche nur noch die ursprüngliche Form gemein)
>       jemandem, einer Sache gemein sein (gehoben: mehreren Personen oder Sachen gemeinsam sein oder gehören: allen war die Liebe zur Musik gemein)

## gemeinsam

From [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/gemeinsam):

> *Bedeutungen:*
>
> (1) mehreren Personen oder Sachen zugleich eigen
>     (2) in Gemeinschaft, zusammen mit mindestens einem Anderen
>
> *Beispiele:*
>
> (1) Die beiden Länder verfolgen gemeinsame Interessen.
>     (2) Das Buch entstand in gemeinsamer Arbeit der Autoren.

## Conclusion

***Gemeinsam*** can usually be used in two ways:

1. etw. gemeinsam haben (**Eigenschaft**) - *to have sth. in common*
2. etw. gemeinsam (zusammen) tun - *together* (**Activities**, in the sense of: doing sth with sb)

***Gemein*** is restricted to characteristics (**Eigenschaften**), similar to the first usage of *gemeinsam*:

1. jdm./etw. gemein sein

In this case, you would be able to use both *gemein* and *gemeinsam*, but not interchangeably:

**Example**:

> Allen ist die Liebe zur Musik gemein.

(This is more formal, more elegantly put)
changes to:

> Alle haben die Liebe zur Musik gemeinsam.

(*tends* to be more common, colloquial)

This is at least how I feel sounds natural, but I might be mistaken.

**Another Example**:

One would say

> Unsere gemeinsame Arbeit (*work we've done together*)

but not:

> Unsere gemeine Arbeit

## Other

There is also another use for *gemein*:
*sich mit jdm. gemein machen* (to associate with sb. considered unsuitable, [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=sich%20mit%20jdm.%20gemein%20machen))

It was used in a [recent column on zeit.de](http://www.zeit.de/kultur/2015-12/polizei-willkommensfest-dresden-kiyak-deutschstunde):

> Ein "Willkommensfest" für Flüchtlinge? Der Dresdener Polizeichef findet, das sei eine Provokation. ***Damit macht er sich gemein*** mit der Neuen Rechten.

I'm a total amateur when it comes to language, but I wanted to share my research anyway. There is [a similar discussion thread on leo.org](http://dict.leo.org/forum/viewGeneraldiscussion.php?idThread=322241), but they don't seem to have found a satisfying answer either.

Answer (score 2):

The comments already hinted at the various uses for *gemein*.

While in theory you could use *gemein* in many situations where *gemeinsam* fits, I would suggest to use *gemeinsam*. *Gemein* in this meaning is typically used in either old-fashioned, scientific, very formal or lyrical context, and has a slight tendency to be misinterpreted.

As noted in the comment, there are situations where *gemeinsam* cannot be replaced with *gemein*, for example everything that follows this pattern:

> Wir machen etwas gemeinsam.

(Can somebody provide the grammatical term?)

Comment: predicative vs. adverbial? Doesn’t explain all differences as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

*gemein* means (beside other things mentioned in the first comment of the question) *common*, as you said.

E.g. "to have sth. in common with so." = "etw. mit jmdm. gemein haben"

But *gemeinsam* means *together*. So I disagree with the above answer.
"etw. gemeinsam haben" is "to have sth. together" and this is slightly different from "to have sth. in common" (= "etw. gemein haben")